# Cython undefined symbol PyPyExc_TypeError when using cpython

Tags: python, cython, cpython

My Cython library compiles fine but when I try to import it I get `undefined symbol: PyPyExc_TypeError`. I'm not sure where this is coming from. `PyPyExc_TypeError` does not appear anywhere in the Cython generated file. I installed Cython 0.27.3 in a virtualenv to make sure it was clean.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./hi.so: undefined symbol: PyPyExc_TypeError
>>>
```

Here's my contrived `hi.pyx` to demonstrate

```
cpdef hi():
    return 'hi'
```

Compiled with

```
cython hi.pyx
gcc hi.c -I /usr/lib/python2.7/ -fPIC -shared -o hi.so -pthread -lpython2.7
```

Comment: This symbol is from pypy. It looks as if the pypy’s headers were used by gcc

Comment: `/usr/lib` isn't usually a directory you add to the include path

Comment: @DavidW Well I'll be...   Because of my PyPy installation that's where it was picking up Python.h when it couldn't find it in `/usr/lib`